# AngularJS directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm creating a drag & drop directive in AngularJS. I'm having problems with my `directive` being inside an `ng-repeat`.

The problem is that when I drag my element onto a droppable div, it always takes the last element from the list. If I drag the first one in the list it still takes the last one being dropped. This is my HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in source">
   <div draggable="#divDrop" drop-model="otherList" push-object="data">
      {{data.name}} {{data.price}}
   </div>
</li>

<div id="divDrop" class="alert alert-info">Drag your data into this box</div>
```

Finally I have a simple directive as follows:

```
app.directive('draggable', function($timeout) {
            return {
                scope: {
                    dropModel: '=',
                    pushObject: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var draggableEl = attrs.draggable;

                        $(draggableEl).droppable({
                            drop: function (event, ui) {
                                scope.dropModel.push(scope.pushObject);
                                scope.$apply();
                            }
                        });

                        $(element).draggable({
                            revert: true,
                            revertDuration: 0
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Just to be clear, `scope.pushObject` is always the last item in the `ng-repeat` and not the item being dragged.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunkr?  You might be better off going with a more programatic method here, where you grab the index of the item in your "source" object, copy it, then insert into the new div, and remove it from the previous source object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the scope of each item being dragged like this:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    var data = $(ui.draggable).scope().data;

    scope.dropModel.push(data);
    scope.$apply();
}
```

Then you wouldn't need `pushObject` on the directive scope.

http://plnkr.co/eo7zCRu0JA1mLdVekGiK

Comment: Thanks, makes it even simpler and more generic!